# Can I return execution to statement throws exception

Tags: c#, exception

Say I've this:

```
try
{
    statement 1;
    statement 2; //this throws exception
    ...
}
catch (TheExceptionType e)
{
    ...
    //here I need to return execution to statement 2
}
```

Is this possible?

**Remark: goto won't work according to C# reference.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can statement 1 throw an exception?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a `do` or `while` or `for` loop to repeat functionality.

```
var success = false;

while (!success)
{
    try
    {
        ... // statements that may throw
        success = true;
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

As written, this could become an infinite loop. I prefer to do a `for` and try x times before giving up.